# Does Number() explicitly call toString() when value is neither number nor string type? (e.g. function)

Tags: javascript, function

As the documentation describes this behaviour for parseInt(), but not for the Number() constructor called as a function, I was looking for some insight on whether this is reliable and if there's a reference to this from an official source. Sample code:

```js
let adder = (function () {
    let sum = 0

    return function add(num) {
        sum += num
        add.toString = () => sum //method is overwritten to return value
        return add
    }
})()

console.log(Number(adder(5)(2)(3))) // => 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor). Calling `Number` will call `ToNumeric(value)` with the argument, which will call
[ToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) with the argument, which will (usually) call
[OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) with the argument and a hint of `number`, which does:

1. Assert: Type(O) is Object.
2. Assert: hint is either string or number.
3. If hint is string, then

   1. Let methodNames be « "toString", "valueOf" ».
4. Else,

   1. Let methodNames be « "valueOf", "toString" ».
5. For each element name of methodNames, do

   1. Let method be ? Get(O, name).
   2. If IsCallable(method) is true, then

      1. Let result be ? Call(method, O).
      2. If Type(result) is not Object, return result.
6. Throw a TypeError exception.

So, in the case of converting an object to a numeric primitive, will first attempt to call a `valueOf` method on the object, if it exists. If such a method doesn't exist, it'll attempt to call the `toString` method on the object.

Yes, relying on `toString` being invoked in case `valueOf` doesn't exist is reliable.

Live snippet illustrating how `valueOf` is called first, if it exists:

```js
let adder = (function () {
    let sum = 0

    return function add(num) {
        sum += num
        add.toString = () => {
            console.log('toString called');
            return sum; //method is overwritten to return value
        };
        add.valueOf = () => {
            console.log('valueOf called');
            return sum; //method is overwritten to return value
        };
        return add
    }
})()

console.log(Number(adder(5)(2)(3))) // => 10
```

If the object doesn't have an own property of `toString` or `valueOf`, `Object.prototype.toString` will be called, resulting in `[object Object]` - but that won't be coercable to a number, resulting in `NaN`.

```js
let adder = (function () {
    let sum = 0

    return function add(num) {
        sum += num
        return add
    }
})()

console.log(Number(adder(5)(2)(3))) // => 10
```

And if the object doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype` and doesn't have `toString` or `valueOf` anywhere in its prototype chain, an error will be thrown:

```js
let adder = Object.create(null);

console.log(Number(adder))
```